# Cronjob doesn't execute python script

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I want to use Cron to execute my python script every hour of the day. Therefore I created a cronjob that looks like: `@hourly /home/pi/Desktop/repository/auslastung_download/auslastung.py`

The cronjob should execute the following script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime, date


def get_auslastung_lichtenberg():
    try:
        url = "https://www.mcfit.com/de/fitnessstudios/studiosuche/studiodetails/studio/berlin-lichtenberg/"
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        driver.get(url)

        html_content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

        elems = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sc-iJCRLp eDJvQP'})
        #print(elems)
        auslastung = str(elems).split("<span>")[1]
        #print(auslastung)
        auslastung = auslastung[:auslastung.rfind('</span>')]
        #print(auslastung)
        auslastung = str(auslastung).split("Auslastung ")[1]
        #print(auslastung)
        auslastung = auslastung[:auslastung.rfind('%')]
        print(auslastung)

        now = datetime.now()

        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        #print("Current Time =", current_time)
        today = date.today()
        print(today)

        ergebnis = {'date': today, 'time':  current_time,'studio': "Berlin Lichtenberg", 'auslastung': auslastung}

        return ergebnis

    finally:
        try:
            driver.close()
        except:
            pass

"""
import json

with open('database.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(get_auslastung_lichtenberg(), f)
    """

import csv

with open('/home/pi/Desktop/repository/auslastung_download/data.csv', mode='a') as file:
    fieldnames = ['date', 'time', 'studio', 'auslastung']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writerow(get_auslastung_lichtenberg())
```

When executed via `python3 auslastung.py`everything works fine and the script writes into the data.csv file.

Maybe someone can help me :)

Comment: you don't have `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of the script so you need to call `python3` before pointing to the path of your script

Comment: You missed the shebang at the very first line of script ... something similar to `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: I added the #!/usr/bin/python bur it still doesn't work. I also did chmod +x on the file

Comment: Try finding if `/usr/bin/python` is your interpreter for python. Use `which python3` to find it.

Comment: `usr/bin/python` is the interpreter according to `which python`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must ensure that your script runs.

If interactively you run `python3 auslastung.py` why do you invoke your python script differently on your cron.

have you tried to run just `/home/pi/Desktop/repository/auslastung_download/auslastung.py` interactively? without initial `python3`, does it run?

If your script runs with `python3 auslastung.py` on your crontab you should include full path to both interpreter and script:

`@hourly /paht/to/python3 /full/path/to/script.py`

If you made your script to run directly without need to indicate interpreter, just  `/full/path/to/script.py` then on your crontab you should include full path to script:

`@hourly /full/path/to/script.py`

You may include a shebang: a very first line of your script indicate which interpreter is used to execute it. So your first line should be `#!/path/to/your/interpreter`

An you have to ensure then that script has execute permision with `chmod +x auslastung.py`.

Comment: Yes it runs without an initial `python3` command. So it should be an executable due to the `chmod +x` I already did. My crontab entry looks exactly like you described. I frist did `crontab -e` then entered `@hourly /path/to/script.py`. When listing the jobs with `crontab -l`I also see my entry, but it dont run the script every hour